# How do you represent domain object behaviors using methods when a domain object is acted upon and not the actor?

Tags: oop, methods, entity, domain-driven-design

In Domain Driven Design, there is an emphasis of placing behaviors where they correctly belong. I'm not always sure what exactly constitutes "correct," though.

Consider this scenario: **"The client withdraws an amount of money from a bank account."**

Grammatically, we have that:

- 'client' is a **subject**
- 'withdraw' is a **verb**
- 'amount' is a **direct object**
- 'account' is an affected **prepositional object**

Classically, the client would execute this: **account.withdraw(amount)**.

This could be read as: **"The client commands a bank account to withdraw an amount of money."** However, this does not grammatically correspond to the original scenario, since 'bank account' is now the **direct object** and an **infinitive** removes 'withdraw' and 'amount' from the main clause so that the primary idea conveyed is that 'client commands account'.

To adhere to DDD, we should regard this code as precisely describing the original scenario. This implies that the 'withdraw' method does not model a behavior **performed by** the account (the account is not a **subject**), but rather it models a behavior that **indirectly affects** it (the account is a **prepositional object**) and could very well be renamed 'wasWithdrawnFrom'. Moreover, the method argument represents something being affected **by the client** as opposed to **by the object** (it is a **direct object** for **a client subject**, not **an object subject**).

If we extrapolate from this example, we can see that methods may represent **behaviors that affect the object (object is not the subject)** and method arguments may represent **direct objects of a client subject**.

*However, whether or not methods should represent **behaviors performed by objects** is unclear.*

So my question is: **How should we use methods to model object behavior?**

**1) Methods should strictly represent behaviors that affect the object. (The object cannot act as a subject, only a grammatical direct/indirect/prepositional object)**

**2) Methods may represent both behaviors that affect the object as well as behaviors performed by the object. (The object may act as a subject or a grammatical direct/indirect object)**

Comment: Where the state(data fields) is, where the behaviour(method) is.

Comment: That preserves encapsulation, but my question is about how to model a domain with behaviors; your rule does not take into consideration the domain. If we say account.withdraw, it may seem like the 'account' is the acting agent when in fact the client is. Perhaps it'd be better to say account.wasWithdrawnFrom(amount) or customer.withdrawsFromOwnedAccount(amount), since it is clear here that the customer is the actor, the owned account is the affected object, and amount is the thing being acted upon; maybe customer.withdrawsFromOwnedAccount(amount) calls account.wasWithdrawnFrom(amount)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to be stuck in a theoretical thesis. I'm not sure you can apply a theory that works for every scenario/project. Behaviors usually appears when you start bombarding your Model with Use Cases. I try to let the cases dictate behaviors.
To follow your example:

Actor Customer want to withdraw money from Account. The way to do it is like you do Account.Withdraw(Money amount)

But your question "How should we use methods to model object behavior?" is a common DDD question. How to enrich your model with behavior? My best hints is to find your Value Objects. Value objects usually comes with behavior.

In example Account is and Entity (Aggregate root probably). Money (Value object with Currency and Amount) should be withdrawn from an Account. That should be Account Single Responsible (Principle) to control that Account balance and all access to it.
Regarding your (2) question in the end. Methods are absolutely used for change the objects inner state. But when it comes to behaviors performed by the entity/value object like 
Customer.Order(newOrder) or advert.Apply(candidateCV) we can make entities communicate with each other. We can also create chained behaviors through Domain Events which can help us not to leak to much business logic to our application services. See Udi Dahan's blog for that or my blog article regarding Anemic Domain model http://magnusbackeus.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/preventing-anemic-domain-model-where-is-my-model-behaviour/

I Hope you got some ideas. It's difficult to give concrete hints when we are so abstract here. 
/Best regards Magnus

Answer (score 0):

I find that scenario too simple to be real, hence too simplistic to model too. I would reformulate the

**"The client withdraws an amount of money from a bank account."**

to something like

**"The client submits withdrawal request of value xxx $ from his account"** (when I go to my bank I have to fill out a form in order to withdraw money where I state amount, the account number, date and my signature)

There one can spot a request (**command**) to a service (**withdrawal service**) of an client (**client identified by ID**) from his account (**account identified by ID**) and the money value (**money as value object**).

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't think the problem with my example is its oversimplicity; the problem in the fact that it probably does not accurately describe the reality of the banking domain (bank tellers deal with withdrawal requests, not withdrawals). However, we could pretend that my example is in fact what the domain problem entails (ATM machine maybe?) or replace it with a more realistic one ("The client deletes an order" => order.delete), and the question would remain. The point of my question was not to ask a question of the banking domain, but a more general DDD one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't care much about the grammar, as English is my second language so when trying to understand the Domain, I try to understand how the business sees the concepts (Account) and workflows (withdraw an amount) and not to do grammar analysis.

The point of DDD is to model things like they are in the business, so behaviour shows up according to Domain understanding.

in this scenario, for me it's clear that we're working within the Account Operations Bounded Context and at least the Account aggregate root is involved. Of course, in banking terms, probably (I'm guessing here) there will not be a withdrawl but an operation to increase the Debit/Credit part of an account, so most likely the account will register that a debit/credit operation has happened. And a Domain Event is born and published. Then let the domain expert tell you what will happen next.

> "The client deletes an order" => order.delete

Probably the order is never deleted, but its status will changed to 'canceled' or similar. However for that case when an order really should be deleted, the order doesn't delete itself, the Orders repository deletes that order.

Comment: I agree that using English is arbitrary, but DDD prescribes that the model must nicely express domain scenarios, and if my domain experts speak English the model should express coherent English scenarios. In your comment, you attempt to revise my banking and ordering scenarios, which I agree with you are probably incorrect; but the point of my question is not whether or not the scenario is correct, but **assuming that it is**, how withdrawal behavior would be modeled. How about this:"A user records an exercise amount during a training session." Do we say trainingSession.recordExercise(amount)?

Comment: You won't get the behaviour from analysing grammar, you get it from understanding what the words mean in the business context. I don't think there's a formula you can extract from words that will give you the right behaviour. About the exercise example, I never heard anyone speaking like that. Maybe an user registers her progress in a training session. But then again, I'd have to know how the Domain works and what the stakeholder wants from the app.